# GitHub Actions Disable Auto Cancel When Job Fails

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following GitHub Actions config file (parts removed for simplicity).

```
name: CI
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x, 13.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```

The major problem I'm running into is that lets say the test for Node.js version 8 fails. But the rest succeed. In that event GitHub Actions tends to cancel all the jobs if one job fails.

Is there a way to change this behavior so all jobs will continue to run even if one has a failure? This can be helpful in pinpointing an issue with a specific version.

Comment: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Why-a-matrix-step-will-be-canceled-if-another-one-failed/td-p/30920

Comment: TL;DR: Set [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.fail-fast`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategyfail-fast) to `false` in your workflow.

Comment: @LexLi now on https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27192

Answer (score 44):

Adding `fail-fast: false` under `strategy` works fines for me! :)

```
name: CI
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x, 13.x]
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```